# MediaWiki on Nginx

Tags: nginx, mediawiki, vhosts

I can't get MediaWiki to work on Nginx.
I have it in my /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/wiki dir and in my wiki.domain.com subdomain.

I tried with many vhost examples found over the internet, for instance:

```
server {
server_name wiki.domain.com;
root /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/wiki;
index index.html index.php;
autoindex off;

location / {
 index index.php5;
 error_page 404 = @wiki;
```

}

```
location @wiki {
    rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php5?title=$1&$2 last;
}

location ~ \.php5?$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;    
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php5;     
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

}
```

Or, another:

```
server {
server_name wiki.domain.com;
root /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/wiki;

client_max_body_size 5m;
client_body_timeout 60;

# Remote index.php from URI
rewrite ^/index.php/(.*) /$1  permanent;

location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$") {
            expires max;
            break;
    }
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            return 404;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

}
```

I get 403 Forbidden for wiki.domain.com and 500 Internet Server Error for wiki.domain.com/index.php

In my LocalSettings.php I also set this:
$wgUsePathInfo      = true;

Can you help me..? How should I configure vhost/localsettings to make MW work on Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the issue: it was with [LyricExtension](http://wiki.peacocktech.com/wiki/LyricExtension)! I disabled it and everything started working properly :)

Comment: Could you add more information, if someone has the same problem in the future? What extension was it? Do you know what exactly was the problem?

Comment: Oh yes, it was the LyricExtension:
http://wiki.peacocktech.com/wiki/LyricExtension

Don't know why.. :o

Comment: Undeserving answer of the top result on google when you search "mediawiki nginx".